# How to start google keep extension in Mac from command line for a particular profile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-keep

How to start Google Keep extension in Mac OS X from command line for a particular profile?

I did some research online but couldn't get any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome version 32 (and 31) on Mac, Chrome will generate .app bundles for packaged apps. They are enabled when you install a new app from the "[For Your Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/for_your_desktop)" webstore collection (Keep is one of them), and get the App Launcher.

You can also get the launcher by visiting https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher

Once you have a .app bundle for Google Keep, it should show up in Spotlight. If you drag the spotlight result directly into a terminal window you'll get its path, which includes the profile ID. Then you can use a trick like

```
open -a 'Default hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki'
```

which (for me) opens Keep in my first Chrome profile. Replacing "Default" with "Profile 1", "Profile 2", etc. will open it for other profiles.